# Basing initial size of textarea with min-content

Tags: html, css

I'm have a form with some  tags. The from is pre-populated, but I cannot seem to be able to assign the initial height of the item using min-content. For instance:

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem 0 0.5rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.item > textarea {
    width:100%;
    margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
    min-height: 20px;
    height: min-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sandbox index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item"><label for="">some label</label><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus autem </textarea></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't need to resize based on input (e.g. I've seen other questions, that involve javascript in some ways). But it seems to me there really should be a way to set it directly with css if it only needs to remain static, non?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `contenteditable` that looks like textarea with css?

```css
.textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sandbox index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item"><label for="">some label</label><span contenteditable class="textarea" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus autem </span></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can have a static placeholder using CSS

```
.textarea[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus autem";
  color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Hrmph..... yes I mean I could, but because that's a Django project, by default it puts my content in a TextArea widget thingy.... which means if I use css to style the text area so that it min-content properly, I don't have to touch the backend.

However if I do as you suggest, which works for the front-end purpose, then that means that all the fields using the text-area widget have to be refactored....

Comment: That's an interesting option, but if there's as way to make the TextArea tag behave, that would be my preferred option. I'll accept that if nothing else comes up.